# How to do statistic test if I know only one changed parameter?

Tags: probability, statistics

I have next condition of some study.
We have 15 dogs that passed some test before specific therapy and after one week of therapy its passed it again and 13 pets had positive dynamic and participants with positive effect be the random variable Y. $Y_{obs}$ is 13

First I need establish $H_0$ and alternative hypotheses.
My $H_0$ that nothing changed and alternative that therapy has positive effect to the participants. Can I establish $H_a$ that mean generally changed or in this case only that the therapy has positive effect?

Next I should describe distribution. My guess that it is binomial with equal probability. The therapy has positive effect or don't have.
Then I should give answer does therapy has effect or not with significant level 1%. And here if it binomial distribution I use mean = np and std$=\sqrt{npq}$

Thank you friends!

Answer (score 1):

From your description, I suppose you have $x = 13$ successes among $n = 15$ subjects and for the success probability $p$ you want to test $H_0: p = 0.5$ against $H_a: p > 0.5.$

**Exact binomial test.** If you are doing an exact binomial test, then the null distribution is $\mathsf{Binom}(n = 15, p = 1/2)$ and the
P-value of the test is the probability, under this distribution,
of getting 13 or more successes. You could use the binomial
pdf to find this probability as
$$P(X \ge 13) = \frac{{15\choose 13}}{2^{15}}+
\frac{{15\choose 14}}{2^{15}}+\frac{{15\choose 15}}{2^{15}} = 0.0037.$$

So the P-value of the test is $0.0037 < 0.01 = 1\%$ and you
can reject $H_0$ at the 1% level in favor of $H_a,$ concluding
that the therapy has a significantly positive effect.

In R statistical software you can compute this P-value directly
or by using the binomial PDF function `dbinom` or the binomial
CDF function `pbinom` as shown below:

```
sum(choose(15, 13:15)/2^15)
[1] 0.003692627
sum(dbinom(13:15, 15, .5))
[1] 0.003692627
1 - pbinom(12, 15, .5)
[1] 0.003692627
```

In R, the procedure `binom.test` gives the same P-value along
with additional information.

```
binom.test(x=13, n=15, alt="greater")

        Exact binomial test

data:  13 and 15
number of successes = 13, number of trials = 15, p-value = 0.003693
alternative hypothesis: 
  true probability of success is greater than 0.5
95 percent confidence interval:
 0.6365582 1.0000000
sample estimates:
probability of success 
             0.8666667
```

**Test using normal approximation.** With $n = 15$ subjects you have enough data to use a normal approximation
to test $H_0: p = 0.5$ against $H_a: p > 0.5.$

If $X \sim \mathsf{Binom}(n=15, p=0.5),$ then (as you say) $\mu = E(X) = np = 7.5$ and $\sigma = SD(X) = \sqrt{np(1-p)} = 1.936492.$ Then you can find the approximate P-value by
standardizing and using printed tables of the standard normal CDF. [The use of 12.5 instead of 13 is called a 'continuity correction.]

$$P(X \ge 13) = P(X > 12.5) = 
P\left(\frac{X = \mu}{\sigma}> \frac{12.5 -7.5}{1.0365}\right)\\
\approx P(Z > 2.55) = 0.0054.$$

The approximate P-value is not quite the same as the exact one above, but it still indicates rejection of $H_0$ at the 1% level.

The figure below shows the PDF of $\mathsf{Binom}(15, 0.5)$ along with the density curve of the approximating normal distribution. The exact P-value is the sum of the heights of
the blue bars to the right of the vertical dotted line.
The approximate P-value is the area under the normal density curve to the right of that line.

[image]

R code for figure:

```
x = 0:15;  PDF = dbinom(x, 15, .5)
hdr = "PDF of BINOM(15, 0.5) with Normal Approx."
plot(x, PDF, type="h", ylim=c(0,.25), col="blue", lwd=2, main=hdr)
 abline(h=0, col="green2")
 abline(v=0, col="green2")
 curve(dnorm(x, 15/2, sqrt(15/4)), add=T, col="red")
 abline(v = 12.5, lwd=2, lty="dotted")
```